# losing internet connection while sending multiple API calls one by one

Tags: javascript, api, http

I want to make multiple API calls one by one and the second one will be dependent on the result of the first one. What if I lost my internet connection in between each call?

Example:

```
const test1 = async () => {

  const var1 = await function1()

  // loss of internet connection or browser gets shut down

  const var2 = await function2(var1)

}
```

Will var2 get executed or will it have expected result returned to me? If not, what are the workarounds to make sure two calls get executed?

Comment: No, function2 will not execute. You can solve this problem using setTimeOut. But it is not properly solution. I think there is no solution.

Comment: "*what are the workarounds to make sure two calls get executed?*" - why do you *need* the second call to be executed, and how strongly do you need it?

Answer (score 1):

If you try to call api without connection, you get an error. In your case error will be thrown when you call `await someApiCall()`. Workaround is to put some kind of retry logic.